# All combinations of distributing items from a list into a fixed number of bins in python?

Tags: python, combinatorics

Say I have a list of numbers (not in any specific order, and repeats are allowed). For example

```
[3 3 7 6]
```

Say I have a set number of bins (no capacity restriction, this is not an optimization question), for example 3 bins. I want to generate all combos of ways I could distribute my list into the bins. The order must stay the same and bins cannot be empty. My desired output would be

```
[3 3] [7] [6]

[3] [3 7] [6]

[3] [3] [7 6]
```

You could think of this as an equivalent combinatorics question, which would be saying you have the string '3376' and you need to insert two "spits" which create three sub-strings, like so:

```
33|7|6

3|37|6

3|3|76
```

and my goal would be to generate a list of all the valid spitted-up strings. Would prefer an answer (or starting point/clue) in python.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail? What is your problem? SO is not a code writing service. See [ask] and provide your [mre] and explain your specific problem.

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: You just need to generate integer pairs `(x,y)` such that `0 < x < y < len(lst)`. Then `lst[0:x] + lst[x:y] + lst[y:] == lst`, and none of the three slices are empty.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
from itertools import combinations

vals = [3, 3, 7, 6]
nbins = 3

for c in combinations(range(1, len(vals)), nbins - 1):
    bvals = [vals[i:j] for i, j in zip((0,) + c, c + (len(vals),))]
    print(bvals)
```

This produces:

```
[[3], [3], [7, 6]]
[[3], [3, 7], [6]]
[[3, 3], [7], [6]]
```